# "installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status" on MacOS

Tags: macos, anaconda, rstudio

I mostly work in Python to do data analysis, but am trying to learn R stats as well. Python, Pandas, etc are installed via Anaconda on my Mac laptop.

Today I downloaded R Studio onto my laptop, and tried running `install.packages("tidyverse")` to get started in R. I ran into this error:

```
ERROR: dependencies ‘rvest’, ‘xml2’ are not available for package ‘tidyverse’
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘tidyverse’ had non-zero exit status
```

After Googling for a while I came across a few instances of this [exact](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31008877/unable-to-install-rvest-package) or [similar](https://blog.zenggyu.com/en/post/2018-01-29/installing-r-r-packages-e-g-tidyverse-and-rstudio-on-ubuntu-linux/) issue. However, the solutions are *not for* Mac, e.g.,

`sudo apt install libcurl4-openssl-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev`

It turns out Anaconda has already installed `libcurl`, `libxml2` and `openssl` for me. Is there a way to get Rstudio to ... "look" (?) ... for the compiled libraries it needs where Anaconda has installed them?

Answer (score 0):

If you know where the libraries are (say `/my/lib/path`) then you could use [`withr::with_makevars`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/withr/versions/2.1.1/topics/with_makevars) to supplement the library search path.  Something like

```
library(withr)

with_makevars(c(PKG_LIBS="-L/my/lib/path"), install.packages("tidyverse"), assignment="+=")
```

Personally, I would try to limit this to only the specific packages in tidyverse that are failing, and not the whole umbrella package.